# Unable to use button to open drawer with LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED after recent update

Tags: java, android

```
mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

I used to have this line of code to disable swipe gesture but the top toggle button to open the drawer. I found that after the latest update of the support library, it no longer works properly. I cannot open the drawer by either the toggle button or swipe gesture. I need to uncomment the line to open the drawer.

Does anyone know what needs to be changed?

I have also changed `setDrawerListener` to `addDrawerListener` because the former is depreciated.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected DrawerLayout mDrawer;

    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawer,toolbar,0,0);

        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        // Disable drawer's swiping function
        mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View contentView = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResource(), null, false);

        FrameLayout mainContent = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);

        mainContent.addView(contentView, 0);

        inflateDrawerItem();
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set listen for the Toolbar and when the toggle button is clicked.Here is a reference.

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

    public class HelloDrawerActivity extends Activity
    {

        private String[] mPlanetTitles;
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
        private ListView mDrawerList;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_drawer);

            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            // init the ListView and Adapter, nothing new
            initListView();

            // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
            // opens
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                    GravityCompat.START);

            mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                    R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                    R.string.drawer_close)
            {

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view)
                {

                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }

                /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                {

                    invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                                // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                }
            };

            // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

            // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            // Note: getActionBar() Added in API level 11
        }

        private void initListView()
        {
            mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

            mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);

            // Set the adapter for the list view
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.list_item, mPlanetTitles));
            // Set the list's click listener
            mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id)
                {
                    // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the
                    // drawer
                    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
            // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event
            if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
            // Handle your other action bar items...

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

---

```
public class DrawerActivity extends Activity
{
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // when button be presses，drawer open
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen for the Toolbar's [Navigation onClick listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

and check when the toggle button is clicked, then call openDrawer/closeDrawer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer(int)

Answer (score 0):

Use mDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);